# ECMA 6 support in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I just tried out Nashorn and it seems not to support `Array.prototype.fill`.  Is this surprising?  Is there a timeline somewhere for Nashorn's intended support?  Is the best way to get an array of say 5 0s in Nashorn currently `Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(x=>0)`?

Comment: You always can use transpilers and polyfills :-)

Comment: Asking about the plans of the Nashorn project is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Unfortunately https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ doesn't include Nashorn.

Comment: @Bergi : It does include Nashorn : Looks for JJS

Comment: @EmmanuelDevaux Oh, cool that it does now ([since February](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/commit/11a133c3ccd93437484a990aa657f336fccad973#diff-ca0f8d6af0c57ea63bddc9086afc0bc2))!

Comment: They're already getting rid of the Nashorn engine: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335.

This is done in favour of the more proprietary GraalVM: https://www.graalvm.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is partial support for ES6 in Java9 and more coming later:
https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/nashorn-javascript-engine-jdk9.html

Also see:
http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/292

Answer (score 4):

This documentation would have me believe that you can get ES6 even in Java 8 by using `-Dnashorn.args=--language=es6`:

https://developer.oracle.com/databases/nashorn-javascript-part2

Indeed, I managed to get some basic ES6 support from Clojure (adding `:jvm-opts ["-Dnashorn.args=--language=es6"]` to `project.clj`), though I was still not able to load the library I wanted, so there may indeed still be pieces missing.

Comment: The above link seems to be broken, this is the correct link
https://developer.oracle.com/databases/nashorn-javascript-part2.html