# Run Javascript code with export function in Java with Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Is it possible to run a Javascript code containing export functions in Java with Nashorn? I'm new in Nashorn so I am not sure whether there is restriction for the js code to have. Also how do I pass the arguments from Java to the js code?

The Javascript code looks like this (taken from [here](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/blob/072ed67bc8053379adc019ac987c681a20c6f406/src/circleintersection.js)):

```
/** Given two circles (containing a x/y/radius attributes),
returns the intersecting points if possible.
note: doesn't handle cases where there are infinitely many
intersection points (circles are equivalent):, or only one intersection point*/
function circleCircleIntersection(p1, p2) {
    var d = distance(p1, p2),
        r1 = p1.radius,
        r2 = p2.radius;

    // if to far away, or self contained - can't be done
    if ((d >= (r1 + r2)) || (d <= Math.abs(r1 - r2))) {
        return [];
    }

    var a = (r1 * r1 - r2 * r2 + d * d) / (2 * d),
        h = Math.sqrt(r1 * r1 - a * a),
        x0 = p1.x + a * (p2.x - p1.x) / d,
        y0 = p1.y + a * (p2.y - p1.y) / d,
        rx = -(p2.y - p1.y) * (h / d),
        ry = -(p2.x - p1.x) * (h / d);

    return [{x: x0 + rx, y : y0 - ry },
            {x: x0 - rx, y : y0 + ry }];
}

/** Returns the center of a bunch of points */
function getCenter(points) {
    var center = {x: 0, y: 0};
    for (var i =0; i < points.length; ++i ) {
        center.x += points[i].x;
        center.y += points[i].y;
    }
    center.x /= points.length;
    center.y /= points.length;
    return center;
}
```

As an example I would like to invoke getCenter function in the js by supplying multiple Points using the code:

```
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    //      engine.eval("print('Hello World!');");
    engine.eval(new FileReader("circleintersection.js"));

    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

    Point a = new Point(3,2);
    Point b = new Point(5,3);
    Point c = new Point(1,4);
    Point d = new Point(2,5);
    Point e = new Point(6,6);

    Point[] points = {a,b,c,d,e};

    Point result = (Point) invocable.invokeFunction("getCenter", points);
    System.out.println(result.x);
```

But it gave me error like

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror cannot be cast to Point

How can I get the result from the js code?

Comment: Is it possible to call a Javascript function from Java using Nashorn? Yes. But `export` has nothing to do with it. You'll need the `ScriptEngine` and then you can either `eval` to call your function or get an `Invocable` to call your function.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so it doesn't matter if it is export function or normal function as long as I call the function itself with ScriptEngine?

Comment: The same scriptengine that loaded the js functions. Not just any scriptengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nashorn does not *fully* support ECMA6 features and export is one of them and not supported.

References:

[ECMA 6 support in Nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038418/ecma-6-support-in-nashorn)

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/292

It started to support some from JDK8 itself, and some in JDK 9. But I couldn't find evidence of it supporting *export*.

> Also how do I pass the arguments from Java to the js code?
>   If you have the following function

```
var fun1 = function(name) {
    print('Hi there from Javascript, ' + name);
    return "greetings from javascript";
};

var fun2 = function (object) {
    print("JS Class Definition: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(object));
};
```

Then, you can do,

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("script.js"));

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("fun1", "Peter Parker");
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(result.getClass());

// Hi there from Javascript, Peter Parker
// greetings from javascript
// class java.lang.String
```

This was taken from https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/

Comment: will it be ok if i just remove the export so that it is only a normal function?

Comment: I already tried your code but it still gave me error, please take a look at the updated question for my code implementation